# Exhaustive list of REASONs why a host/server might be down (nmap --reason)

Tags: nmap

I'd like to have reference on how to get
exhaustive REASONs why a host/server might be down in "PORT STATE SERVICE REASON VERSION" (below) of `nmap` using the `--reason` option.

```
--------------------------------------------------
PORT   STATE    SERVICE   REASON      VERSION
17/tcp filtered qotd      no-response
18/tcp filtered msp       no-response
...
--------------------------------------------------
```

here `no-response` is one, but there might be others that `nmap` may return.

I have read

- https://geek-university.com/nmap/
- https://geek-university.com/nmap/the-reason-flag/
- https://nmap.org/book/vscan.html
- https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

The full list of reasons may be found in [the `portreasons.cc` file](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/portreasons.cc#L171) in the `nmap` source distribution.

The list, at the time of writing, contains the following reasons:

```
abort
addressmask-reply
admin-prohibited
arp-response
beyond-scope
conn-refused
dest-unreach
echo-reply
host-prohibited
host-unreach
init-ack
ipid-change
localhost-response
nd-response
net-prohibited
net-unreach
no-ipid-change
no-response
no-route
param-problem
perm-denied
port-unreach
proto-response
proto-unreach
reject-route
reset
script-set
source-quench
split-handshake-syn
syn-ack
tcp-response
time-exceeded
timestamp-reply
udp-response
unknown-response
user-set
```

Comment: BTW

where can I get a tutorial on how to format post messages I post on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

I saw https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/500692/revisions and i must admit
that my post was badly formated

sorry for that

Comment: @user2901196 Some text that may help when editing posts is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @user2901196 To be honest, I didn't know some of the stuff there :-)